# GNU assembler not found, install/update gas-preprocessor

Tags: gcc, assembly, ffmpeg, clang

I want to cross compile FFmpeg using clang. Here is part of my configure.

```
 ./configure --cross-prefix=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
```

The var `TOOLCHAIN` is tool chain dir. After configured, the output is.

```
 C compiler                toolchains/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
 C library                 bionic
 host C compiler           gcc
 host C library
```

I want to change compiler to `clang`. So I `export CC=${TOOLCHAIN}/bin/clang`. However the configuration is keeping `gcc`. How can I use clang and clang++ compiler?

I tried to configure `CC` like this.

```
--cc="${TOOLCHAINS_PREFIX}/bin/clang"
```

But I got an error.

> GNU assembler not found, install/update gas-preprocessor

Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

I tried `--disable-asm` then I can pass configuration test. But the generated libs's size increased.

Comment: Can we have more information please? What is the environment variables for you? clang is GCC. it's a wrapper for it.

Comment: *But the generated libs's size increased.*  I would think the more important factor is that decode speed decreases (or CPU/battery usage increases) by a large factor for some codecs, like probably h.264.

Comment: @PeterCordes Yes I use x264 and I want to know can I use clang and also enable  asm?

Comment: @CoXier: You're building FFmpeg; its x264 encoder is just a wrapper for the x264 library which you have to build separately.  If you meant the h.264 software *decoder*, yes that is part of the FFmpeg source tree, and it's called `ff264`.  (x264 is not the name of the format, just of one encoder library that isn't part of FFmpeg.)  Anyway, I don't know anything about building it on ARM or with clang, sorry.

Comment: What command / test made `./configure` decide to print that error message?  Look at the log and see what failed.

Comment: As my question says, `GNU assembler not found, install/update gas-preprocessor`. But it passed when I disable-asm.

Comment: No, silly, I'm not asking what error message it printed, I'm asking what source it tried to build with what command which failed and led it to print that message.  `./configure` works by trying to compile or assemble things and seeing if it gets an error or not.  So you can figure out what's really going on by looking at `config.log` or something.  Search for the place it printed the error and work back from there.

Comment: @PeterCordes When I `./configure`, it failed.  And I fount who led it to print the message. https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/release%2F4.0/configure line:5476

Comment: `check_as as_arch_directive ".arch armv7-a"` (line 5476) might be the first one that tries to use the assembler directly, rather than using inline asm?  IDK, see if your clang supports that `.arch armv7-a` directive in a `.S` file by itself.

Comment: @PeterCordes How can I check if my clang support that .arch armv7-a directive in a .S file by itself.

Comment: By literally putting that line in a file and compiling it with `clang -c`.  You're asking a question tagged `clang` and `assembly`; you know how to use the tools, right?  If you're not asking a programming question (e.g. how to dig into this and track down the problem), this might belong on superuser or something.

Comment: I create a file named `test_clang` and I `clang -c test_clang`. Then I get output `clang: warning: test_clang: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]` .

Comment: call it `test_clang.S` so the compiler knows its an asm source file.  With no extension, it probably assumed it was an object file or something, and not an input to be compiled.

Comment: test_clang.S:1:28: error: unexpected token in argument list